# Nested list from list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
mylst = ['bla,bli', 'blula', 'blabla,bloblu,blibla', 'bla']
```

How can it be transformed into a nested list such as:

```
mylst = [['bla','bli'], ['blula'], ['blabla','bloblu','blibla'], ['bla']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> mylst = ['bla,bli', 'blula', 'blabla,bloblu,blibla', 'bla']
>>> mylst = [item.split(',') for item in mylst]
>>> mylst
[['bla', 'bli'], ['blula'], ['blabla', 'bloblu', 'blibla'], ['bla']]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to split on commas, just do so in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mylst = [elem.split(',') for elem in mylst]
```

The [`str.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) produces new lists:

```
>>> mylst = ['bla,bli', 'blula', 'blabla,bloblu,blibla', 'bla']
>>> [elem.split(',') for elem in mylst]
[['bla', 'bli'], ['blula'], ['blabla', 'bloblu', 'blibla'], ['bla']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Really simple actually!

```
myLst2 = map(lambda x: x.split(','), mylst)
```

As pointed out by Martijn Pieters in python3 this will return a map iterator. To get a list do:

```
mapIter = map(lambda x: x.split(','), mylst)
myLst2 = list(mapIter)
```

Comment: In Python 3, this'll return an map iterator object, not a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the feedback! Updated my code :)